# What type of object is a copied Excel chart in Word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have copied a chart from Excel to Word and I need to resize it now. All with VBA via Access.

Can someone tell me, what kind of object the chart is, or how I can get hold of it?

```
xlSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=1, Size:=1, Format:=-4147
wdDoc.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=3, Placement:=0, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an `InlineShape` object. A collection of InlineShapes can be accessed at the document level:

```
wdDoc.InlineShapes(Index)
```

I believe the Index corresponds to the order in the document, not their order of creation, so if you know it's location in the document relative to other InlineShapes (First: Index=1 or Last: Index = .Count), you could access it that way.

There is also an InlineShapes property for the Range object. So if you know (say) which paragraph you've pasted the shape into, you can access it with

```
Paragraphs(MyPara).Range.InlineShapes(Index)
```

Hope that helps